# How to use group_by to compare averages between groups

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I am using this hiphop data set (https://www.dropbox.com/s/5d8fwxrj3jtua1z/hiphop.csv?dl=0). I am attempting to compare the averages values of each music type (into, vocal, classical, folk, rock, country, pop, alternative, hiphop, and unclassifiable) between males and females. I am grouping by the sex variable to get the averages for each level and each variable using the following code.

```
music_diff <- hiphop %>%
  select(subj, sex, age, ethnic, ethnic_binary, intl:unclassifiable)
sex_music_diff <- music_diff %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarize(avg_intl=mean(intl), avg_vocal=mean(vocal), avg_classical =mean(classical), avg_folk=mean(folk), avg_rock=mean(rock), avg_country =mean(country), avg_pop=mean(pop), avg_alt = mean(alternative), avg_hiphop=mean(hiphop), avg_unclassifiable=mean(unclassifiable), .groups="keep")
```

This gives me the table of averages for male and female subjects inside each group. What I want to do now is use the output it gives me to find variables that are different between males and females. In other words, I want to subtract avg_intl for males and females, avg_vocal for males and females, etc, etc, and return a list of differences for each variable. I tried:

```
sex_music_diff %>%
+ avg_intl$Male - avg_intl$Female
```

But I get an error that says "3 arguments passed to '$' which requires 2". Not sure what's a better way to go about this. Ideally it would be one step for all variable differences that would return a data frames of all the differences. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to do this in `%>%`, subset the 'avg_int' based on a logical vector

```
library(dplyr)# 1.0.0
sex_music_diff %>%
        ungroup %>%
        summarise(Diff = avg_intl[sex == 'Male'] - avg_intl[sex == 'Female'])
#  Diff
#1  0.3
```

If we want to do this for all the 'avg' variables

```
sex_music_diff %>%
        ungroup %>%
        summarise(across(starts_with('avg'), 
             ~ .[sex == 'Male'] - .[sex == 'Female']))
#avg_intl avg_vocal avg_classical avg_country avg_pop avg_hiphop avg_unclassifiable
#1      0.3      -1.4          -1.2        -0.2    -0.3       -1.1               -0.2
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
with(sex_music_diff, avg_intl[sex == 'Male'] - avg_intl[sex == 'Female'])
#[1] 0.3
```

Or as there is only two rows, it can be done with `diff`

```
with(sex_music_diff, diff(avg_intl))
#[1] -0.3
```

Or for all the 'avg' variables

```
nm1 <- startsWith(names(sex_music_diff), 'avg')
diff(as.matrix(sex_music_diff[nm1]))
#     avg_intl avg_vocal avg_classical avg_country avg_pop avg_hiphop avg_unclassifiable
#[1,]     -0.3       1.4           1.2         0.2     0.3        1.1                0.2
```

---

Based on the OP's code, the 'avg_intl' is a separate column and 'Sex' is separate.  So, we cannot extract `$Male` or `$Female` as if 'avg_intl' is an object created.

#### data

```
sex_music_diff <- data.frame(sex = c('Male', 'Female'), 
avg_intl = c(5.2, 4.9), avg_vocal = c(6.5, 7.9),
avg_classical = c(1.2, 2.4), avg_country = c(2.3, 2.5), 
avg_pop = c(3.2, 3.5), avg_hiphop= c(2.4, 3.5), 
avg_unclassifiable = c(2.2, 2.4))
```

Comment: How can I do this on multiple variables at once? I want to subtract all my avg variables for males and females and get the output in a vector or data frame. When I run the dplyr version, I get an empty tibble. The base r version works, but I don't know how to do it with multiple diffs at once.

Comment: @HannahHarder in the `dplyr`, I think you need `ungroup` because you used `.groups = 'keep'`

Comment: When I add sex_music_diff %>%
        summarise(across(starts_with('avg'), 
             ~ .[sex == 'Male'] - .[sex == 'Female'])) to my code, it returns an empty data set and says "no data available in table".

Comment: @HannahHarder you had `group_by` with `.groups = 'keep'` can you add `ungroup` before the `summarise`

Comment: @HannahHarder I updated with the data I used and it is working for me

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much. I don't know if I conceptually understand why I needed ungroup, but it did what I needed so I'm happy. Should I just take .groups = keep out in the beginning or will that break something?

Comment: @HannahHarder If you used `.groups = 'keep'`, then it will keep that attribute.  By default, it will do `drop_last` i.e. the last grouping column.

Answer (score 0):

try it this way

```
library(tidyverse)
music_diff %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  summarise(across(intl:unclassifiable, mean, na.rm = T, .names = "avg_{col}")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-sex) %>% 
  pivot_wider(name, names_from = sex, values_from = value) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = Male - Female)

# A tibble: 10 x 4
   name               Female   Male     Diff
   <chr>               <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 avg_intl           0.444  0.255  -0.190  
 2 avg_vocal          0.880  1.57    0.688  
 3 avg_classical      0.752  0.941   0.189  
 4 avg_folk           0.402  0.392  -0.00955
 5 avg_rock           1.93   3.06    1.13   
 6 avg_country        0.786  0.392  -0.394  
 7 avg_pop            1.30   1.10   -0.201  
 8 avg_alternative    2.21   2.16   -0.0568 
 9 avg_hiphop         1.62   1.53   -0.0945 
10 avg_unclassifiable 0.0598 0.0392 -0.0206
```